# Freebase MQL query for topic summary and image?

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm trying to write an [MQL query](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/documentation) to be executed using [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) API's.  I would like to retrieve the topic summary and the image for the topic.

I have been able to work out the below query which will get me the images associated with the [Bill Gates](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/bill_gates) topic.

MQL:

```
[
  {
    "/common/topic/image" : [
      {
        "id" : null
      }
    ],
    "name" : "bill gates",
    "type" : "/people/person"
  }
]
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "/common/topic/image" : [
      {
        "id" : "/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000004fb4c01"
      },
      {
        "id" : "/wikipedia/images/commons_id/4486276"
      }
    ],
    "name" : "Bill Gates",
    "type" : "/people/person"
  }
]
```

For those that may have not run into MQL in the past but are interested in playing around with it.  Check out the [Freebase MQL Query Editor](http://www.freebase.com/tools/queryeditor).

[billg profile page http://i.friendfeed.com/c31a22d9e439eb67b0feeb4ffd64c3b5ed9a8e16](http://i.friendfeed.com/c31a22d9e439eb67b0feeb4ffd64c3b5ed9a8e16)

**UPDATE**

Query that I ended up using:

```
[
  {
    "/common/topic/image" : [
      {
        "id" : null
      }
    ],
    "article" : [
      {
        "content" : null
      }
    ],
    "name" : "bill gates",
    "type" : "/common/topic"
  }
]
```

These results can be combined with narphorium's answer to retrieve the actual data:

```
[
  {
    "/common/topic/image" : [
      {
        "id" : "/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000004fb4c01"
      },
      {
        "id" : "/wikipedia/images/commons_id/4486276"
      }
    ],
    "article" : [
      {
        "content" : null
      },
      {
        "content" : "/guid/9202a8c04000641f800000000903535d"
      }
    ],
    "name" : "Bill Gates",
    "type" : "/common/topic"
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow, it's actually called "Freebase?"

Comment: Yes and it's pretty cool

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The images and topic summaries are stored separately in the content store and are accessible via [another web service API](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/api_trans_raw).

For example, Bill Gates' image can be accessed like this:

http://www.freebase.com/api/trans/raw/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000004fb4c01

Similarly, the GUID for the topic summary can be found by replacing /common/topic/image with /common/topic/article in your query. The results can be accessed again like this:

http://www.freebase.com/api/trans/raw/guid/9202a8c04000641f8000000008bfed35

You can read more about the content store [here](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch04.html#transservice).

Comment: funny, I aluded to the content store in my question (removed in edit cause your answer is better).  But I thought it was only for the images.  I ended up testing for the actual article/content and found that it also was returned but your answer describes it better than I did.  Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn Does this answer stand right as of 2012? Is the Image Service recommended over this?

Answer (score 6):

The new image service provided by freebase can now be used to get the images using the freebase ids, e.g., for Bill Gates following is the image URL:

https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/en/bill_gates

More about this service can be found at: http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Image_Service

Comment: `https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/en/bill_gates?maxwidth=225&maxheight=225&mode=fillcropmid` The default image is rather small.